# How to display MS. Office VML formulas in HTML?

Tags: php, html, formula, vml, omml

I need to process some docx files in php and display them in a html page.

Originally, docx uses OMML to show equations, but it also uses VML to show formulas created by other applications (latex, etc).

I'm able to process OMML formulas, but I'm unable to show VML formulas.

Is there any possible way to do that?

If there's a way to convert them to OMML or MML that would work fine.